# How to sort a nested table that has multiple ng-repeats angularjs

Tags: angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat, sql-order-by

I have searched for a similar example and found lost of examples but none of them have the same datastructure as my json data so I have tried it all without success. This is my json data

```
vm.result = [
  {
    'first': [ 
      {"indicate":"all", "text":"All views"},
      {"indicate":"userview", "text":"User view"},
      {"indicate":"operatorview", "text":"Operator view"}
    ]
  },
  {
    'second': [ 
      {"indicate":"receipts","text":"Receipts"},
      {"indicate":"other", "text":"Other"},
      {"indicate":"error", "text":"Error resolver"}
    ]
  }
];
```

This is my table

```
<table class="table" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-show="column">Key</th>
      <th>Master</th>
      <th>Editable</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="res in vm.result track by $index">
    <tr  ng-repeat="ed in res.first | filter: searchfield | orderBy: 'indicate'  track by $index">
      <td {{ed.indicate}}</td>
      <td>{{ed.text}}</td>
      <td> {{vm.result[1].second[$index].indicate}}</td>
      <td > {{vm.result[1].second[$index].text}}</td>               
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

OrderBy only works for the first array but not the second and yes I have tried removing first after re in the second ng-repeat but then it cannot recognize it as an array. I need this structure in the table so that each array has its own columns for its data. So how to I add orderBy indicate for both arrays?

Expected output:

```
Master           Editable
all      |   All      | receipts   | Receipts
userview | User view  | other      |Other
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @Dushyantha  updated the question with expected output

Comment: The design of this data is very poor. An array of objects each with one property, all with different property names. That is pure madness. There really isn't a good way to consume this

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash dude, this is just an example to simplify the situation, in reality i'm reading old school property files that have different key names that I then give a common  name like "indicate". Also the point of Stackoverflow is to get SUGGESTIONS to solve a problem. If you don't have an answer why write at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of result data is very poor. It is very hard to convert your expected output.
Try to use result array like this or convert to this type of format,

```
$scope.newResult   = [{
     first:{"indicate":"all", "text":"All views"},
    second:{"indicate":"receipts","text":"Receipts"}
  },
  {
     first:{"indicate":"userview", "text":"User views"},
    second:{"indicate":"other","text":"Other"}
  },
  {
     first:{"indicate":"operatorview", "text":"Operator views"},
    second:{"indicate":"error","text":"Error resolver"}
  }
]
```

HTML Code

```
<table >
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Key</th>
      <th colspan="2">Master</th>
      <th colspan="2">Editable</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
 <tr ng-repeat="res in new">
 <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{res.first.indicate}}</td>
    <td>{{res.first.text}}</td>
    <td>{{res.second.indicate}}</td>
    <td>{{res.second.text}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

  </table>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.result = [
  {
    'first': [ 
      {"indicate":"all", "text":"All views"},
      {"indicate":"userview", "text":"User view"},
      {"indicate":"operatorview", "text":"Operator view"}
    ]
  },
  {
    'second': [ 
      {"indicate":"receipts","text":"Receipts"},
      {"indicate":"other", "text":"Other"},
      {"indicate":"error", "text":"Error resolver"}
    ]
  }

];
$scope.new=[];
angular.forEach($scope.result, function(value, key) {
    if(key ===0){
    angular.forEach(value.first, function(val, k) {
     $scope.new.push({'first':val,'second':''});
     })
    }
    if(key ===1){
    angular.forEach(value.second, function(val, k) {
     $scope.new[k].second = val;
     })
    }

});
```

Using this type of mechanism you can get the expected output, but the better way is using good data format for result array.
  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DushyanthaRDDK/5DMjt/20467/) for this.